# How to add toolbar above Ext.dataview.DataView in Sencha touch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, toolbar, dataview

I have a `Ext.dataview.DataView` How can I add toolbar in this view ? I have tried adding it in config, but not working. My dataview got disappeared . Also tried adding toolbar in `initialise()`, again my dataview got disappeared. Any alternatives?

```
Ext.define('Proj.ListItems', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',

    requires : ['Ext.dataview.List'],

    xtype: 'listitms',

    config: {

        xtype: 'dataview',


        id: 'listItemsDataView',

        itemTpl: '<div class="tweetdiv"></div></div>', //
        store:'Item',
        listeners: {

        }


} });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code structure seems wrong specifically inside you `config` block. Perhaps you wanted to have `dataview` as an item....as in:

```
...
config: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'dataview',
            id: 'listItemsDataView',
            itemTpl: '<div class="tweetdiv"></div></div>', //
            store:'Item',
            listeners: {

            }
        },
        ...
    ],
    ...
},
...
```

I don't know you can ignore if thats not the case. Anyways, are you attempting to do something like this: [Demo](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#36YOk).

**Edit:**

This code also worked for me:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyDataView', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
    alias: 'widget.listitms',

    config: {
        id: 'listItemDataView',
        data: [
            {
                string: 'car'
            },
            {
                string: 'bike'
            },
            {
                string: 'van'
            }
        ],
        itemTpl: [
            '<div>Data View Item {string}</div>'
        ],
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'I\'m A Toolbar'
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

Comment: Now Dataview got disappeared now

Comment: Ok its seems like you have a Dataview inside a Dataview?? Is that what you want? I don't think thats possible.

Comment: Nop. I need only one dataview .that is the inner one. I dont care the extend type.

Comment: Ok so if we are going to ignore the `xtype`, then this is what my demo is doing.... What exactly do you mean by the Dataview disappearing? Do you mean disappear as in the data goes out of view when you scroll?

Comment: It didn't displaying dataview. only displaying toolbar

Comment: I have tried ur code , but when I convert it into Ext.define , it's not working

Comment: Can you update your code on what it looks like because your current code is wrong. Something might be causing an issue because I also tested it with `Ext.define` and it works.

Comment: @Harikrishnan I updated my answer with code the works for me.

Comment: Need one more help. adding initialise function again removes the dataview. What can I do?

Comment: @Harikrishnan why do you want to add toolbar in `initialize()` ?? Can you post that function as well ?

Comment: I need to set some data dynamically on toolbar

Comment: So can you post init function as well?